# How do I test for a block at a certain coordinate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I really need help with this command. I need to use this command for my adventure map or else I will never finish it. Here's what I type:

```
/testforblock wool x y z
```

I really need to know this command so I can finish my adventure map.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I have made 4 attempts

Comment: Okay, so show us those attempts.  Showing us what you've tried is very important.

Comment: i have used "/testforblock 987 9 57 wool" "/testforblock wool[x=987,y=9,z=57]" "/testforblock 987 9 57 wool" also i discounted how many attempts i made i actually made 3 :|

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `/testforblock` is:

```
/testforblock <x> <y> <z> <block> [dataValue] [dataTag]
```

You can find the syntax of a command by typing `/help <command>` (e.g: `/help testforblock`), or by [looking on the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#testforblock).

From there, you should be able to see that the coordinates come before the block name, so your command should be:

```
/testforblock x y z wool
```

Comment: also i am using 1.8.9

Comment: @Cow. This should work in 1.8.9

Comment: or maby its a glitch i always have that when i use a coordinate and it actually does all the effects and stuff (tp, testforblock, etc.) from a block next to it

Comment: nope its not that glitch

Comment: i just found that out

Comment: @Cow. Most likely you're misinterpreting coordinates. Press `F3` and look at a block, then coordinates you need to type will be shown after `Looking at:`. http://i.imgur.com/OSWYKCg.png

Comment: that's exactly what i do

Comment: @Cow. If you type `/setblock 987 9 57 sponge`, do you see the block you intend to test turning into a sponge?